# How to decode a fixed array into an object?

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-core

I'm using .NET Core and Json.net to call rest apis to a server, one of the api the server provided has a array of struct, but the struct is represented by a two element array, rather than an object, when I tried to deserialize it to an object, it failed to do so and `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException` was thrown.

The data is like:

```
"entries":[[0,0.26],[50000,0.24],[100000,0.22],[250000,0.2]]
```

My root struct and inner struct are:

```
public class Entry
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public double percent { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    ...
    public Entry[] entries { get; set; }
}
```

So is there a better way to decode this json string to the struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> { "entries":[[0,0.26],[50000,0.24],[100000,0.22],[250000,0.2]] }

You can use the following model to deserialize the json above. Note that you need to use a nested `List`.

```
public class JsonItem
{
    [JsonProperty("entries")]
    public List<List<double>> Entries { get; set; }
}

var json = "{ 'entries':[[0,0.26],[50000,0.24],[100000,0.22],[250000,0.2]] }";
var jsonItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonItem>(json);
```

If you allways have two entries in the list and the first is the value and the second the percent you can change the model like the following.

```
public class Entry
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public double Percent { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
   public Entry[] Entries { get; set; }
}


var item = new Item
{
    Entries = jsonItem.Entries.Select(x => new Entry { Value = (int) x[0], Percent = x[1]}).ToArray()
};
```

Comment: But then both the two fields are in double, one is int the other is double.

Comment: @fluter I've added the code where you can change your dezerialized item to a nice model. Note that it won't validate the input and it will throw an exception when it isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [jagged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) float array for `entries`:

```
public class Item
{
    public float[][] entries { get; set; }
}


var serialized = "{\"entries\":[[0,0.26],[50000,0.24],[100000,0.22],[250000,0.2]]}";

var deserialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(serialized);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public class Entry
{
    public Entry(double[] vals)
    {
        if (vals.Length == 2)
        {
            value = (int)vals[0];
            percent = vals[1];
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("invalid entry");
    }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public double percent { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Item
{        
    [JsonProperty(propertyName: "entries")]
    public List<double[]> rawEntries { get; set; }

    public Entry[] entries
    {
        get
        {
            return rawEntries.Select(arr => new Entry(arr)).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work, the problem is not in the attributes or class members, it's to decode the data of array to the object.